# Delete a table row by an ID which is inside hidden field

Tags: jsp, servlets, html-table

I have a table which generates its rows in a while loop as follows in JSP, (I use a hidden field in each row to get the specific ID and POST it to the servlet)

```
<tr>
    <td><center><%  out.print(rs1.getString("teamid"));%></center><input name="tid" type="hidden" value="<%out.print(rs1.getString("teamid"));%>"/></td>
    <td><center><%  out.print(rs1.getString("teamname"));%></center></td>
    <td><center><%  out.print(rs1.getString("teaminitials"));%></center></td>
    <td><center><%  out.print(rs1.getString("teamdesc"));%></center></td>  
    <td><center><input type="submit" class="greenbutton" name="delete" value="Delete"/></center></td>
</tr>
```

In the servlet,

```
String buttondelete = request.getParameter("delete");
    if(buttondelete!=null){
    String tid = request.getParameter("tid");

        try {
            clmmodel_database.updateQuery("delete from clm_team where teamid = '"+tid+"'");
            response.sendRedirect("clmview_teamlist.jsp");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
```

But this deletes always the first row of the table, not the row I need to delete. Please show me where I have done the mistake or suggest me a way.

Comment: Why do you want to submit form when delete button is clicked? Instead you can make AJAX call.

Comment: @Aniket I'm not familiar with AJAX :(

Comment: There is no need of using AJAX here.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would seem to be to create a form for each element:

```
<tr>
<td>
Item X
</td>
<td>
<form><input type="hidden" name="id" value="x"/><input type="submit"/></form>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
Item Y
</td>
<td>
<form><input type="hidden" name="id" value="y"/><input type="submit"/></form>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dilukshan Mahendra You can try like this, Which is worked for me. All you need to do is enter your table id and anchor tag class(Every row has anchor tag for row, hence use class)

```
$("#table_name tr td anchor_class").click(function(e) {
// e.preventDefault();
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
var rowid = row.attr('id');
var url = $(this).attr('href');
var ajaxUrl = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.length);
input_box = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?");
if (input_box == true) {
    // Output when OK is clicked
    // Here you are sending your servlet URL to ajax.
    $.ajax({
        url : ajaxUrl,
        type : "POST",
        async : false,
        success : function() {
            $('#'+rowid).remove();
            alert('Record Deleted');
        }
    });

    return false;
} else {
    // Output when Cancel is clicked
    // alert("Delete cancelled");
    return false;
}
});
```

And my html table row looks like,

```
<tr>
   <td>
     <input type="text">
   </td>
   <td>
     <textarea ></textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
     <input class="file1" type="file" value="">
   </td>
   <td>
      <a id="deleteFile2" class="del" href="ur_servlet_url&id=2">Delete</a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: There is no need of using AJAX here. The problem has nothing to do with AJAX.

Comment: May be, If he don't want to reload the page then ajax will help him.

Comment: @VinothKrishnan Can u tell me how to delete data from database using ajax . every time when user clicks the url on button is different . The row is printing by while loop so i can not use id (id can not be duplicate). So how to get the url of the  anchor tag when ever user click the button .

Comment: If you have different question, you can ask as new question by sharing the code whatever you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is

1)`delete` button name on form is common for all rows.

```
String buttondelete = request.getParameter("delete"); //button name on form
```

How do you know which delete button is clicked? There is no identifier.

**Solution**
I am not providing complete code, but giving you the direction.

There is no need of `hidden field`.

You can use [AJAX](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/ajax.html) and write one javascript function which gets the id and pass to servlet

```
<input type="button" class="greenbutton" name="delete" value="Delete" id="<%rs1.getString("teamid");%>" onclick="deleteRow(this.id)"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
function deleteRow(clickedId)
{
   //AJAX call here
  //pass this clickedId to Servlet and delete the row , show response back to user 
}
```

**Related link**

- [Ajax Basics](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/ajax-basics.html) pdf and source code is also available.

Comment: There is no need of using AJAX here. The problem has nothing to do with AJAX.

Comment: @Uooo: Right. Your solution is the best. My thinking is different, When you submit the form all the rows will be flushed. By ajax you can remain on the same page. Avoid reload.

Answer (score 0):

In your rendered HTML table, you will have multiple hidden fields with the same id-attribute:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="hidden" value="ID_1" id="tid" ... > </td>
            <td> ... </td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="hidden" value="ID_2" id="tid" ... > </td>
            <td> ... </td>
        <tr>
        ...
    </table>
</form>
```

That's valid. When sending the form, **all** values of `tid` fields will be sent to the server, as an array. Like: `tid = [ "ID_1", "ID_2", ... ]`

`request.getParameter("tid")` will return you the **first** [value of this list](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter). Hence, always the first row will be deleted.

One possible solution is to remove the hidden input field and give your submit buttons, which you have in each row, a different value:

```
<td> <input type="submit" name="delete" value="<%out.print(rs1.getString("teamid"));%>"/> </td>
```

Then, the browser will see:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> ... </td>
            <td> <input type="submit" name="delete" value="ID_1"/> </td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td> ... </td>
            <td> <input type="submit" name="delete" value="ID_2"/> </td>
        <tr>
        ...
    </table>
</form>
```

And, in your servlet, use:

```
String tid = request.getParameter("delete");
```

This will give you the right ID.

Comment: Then buttons will have captions from "value" attribute, won't they?

Answer (score 0):

use this code to diplay List in the table form:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" name="data" value=<%=rs.getString(5)%> />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here "rs.getString(5)" is the id.
id is a field name/5 is a column index in a table.

**In SERVLET/JSP page**

```
String id = request.getParameter("data"); //Store clicked 'submit' value.

Out.println(id);//Use the variable for your SQL.
```

It worked for me.